# I am confused about the exact meaning of "running" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I'm going to start by telling you about the Yellow Plaque scheme, which has been **running** in Sydney for over forty years.

Does it mean "happening"?

Comment: Please include the reference from which the text has been taken. Where did you find it?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Oxford Dictionary

[**run**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/run)

> 8. **Continue** or be valid or **operative** **for a particular period of time**.

So it means that the Yellow Plaque scheme **started** forty years ago and it **has been operating** since then to this day. It's not just that it's happening right now. As pointed by Rajat, it also have a sense of **continuation** in time.

Answer (score -1):

The word "running" here implies to something that has been in continuation.